# How to select a sibling following an element having a child without using `:has`?

Tags: css

I have the following fragment:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="A">
  <input type="radio" class="B">
</div>
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
```

I would like to select a div, who is following a div containing a checked radio button having the same class.

If I understand [level 4 selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) correctly, this might do the job:

```
div:has(>input[type="radio"].A:checked) ~ div.A,
div:has(>input[type="radio"].B:checked) ~ div.B
```

But my browser does not support the `:has` pseudo class.

Is it possible to work around this without level 4 support?

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector#answer-1014958). I would just change html structure in such case.

Comment: [Edge is the only one considering adding `:has()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has). Please upvote it [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8977591--has).

Comment: @AlexL I am trying this already. ;-)